# Getting Return Count of Select SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, select

I am trying to get the return count of a query. In my case it always be either 0 or 1. I am inserting an customer into my database, I am whether or not they exist already, if they do I throw an exception, if not I insert. This is what I have:

```
string selectQuery = "select ([Cust_Num]) from [TBL_Customer] where [Cust_Num] = '" + myTable.Rows[i][custNum] + "'";
SqlCommand sqlCmdSelect = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, sqlConn);
sqlCmdSelect.Connection.Open();
sqlCmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();

//checks if query returned anything
int queryCount = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmdSelect.ExecuteScalar());
sqlCmdSelect.Connection.Close();
```

Right now, `queryCount` returns `0` if it doesn't exist in my table. But it returns the customer number if it does exist. So instead of returning `1` it returns `123456` which is the customers number.....

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: *(Not directly related to your problem)* [Your code could be vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). You should parameterize your query.

Comment: (Also not directly related but the last guy did it :) throwing an exception to handle a know case is bad form.  Additionally, exceptions are expensive performance wise.

Comment: Well what would be the appropriate action then? Im curious now @THBBFT

Comment: Without knowing the business logic ... I'd say go with either returning 0 (false) or 1 (true) and simply informing the user that they cannot create that account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use `count` aggregate

```
select count(Cust_Num) from [TBL_Customer] where [Cust_Num] = ..
```

for the given cust_num `Count` aggregate will count how many times `cust_num` is present. If `cust_num` exists it will return the `count` else `0`

or even `1` as hardcoded value

```
select 1 from [TBL_Customer] where [Cust_Num] =..
```

here if `cust_num` exists then it will return `1` else nothing will be returned

Comment: And that will still be stored in my queryCount variable?

Comment: @codeFinatic - Am a database guy not sure how your c# query works

Answer (score 0):

A few points here. 
Why you are using ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteScalar in your code ? If you just need the count the above answer given by @NoDisplayName is perfect.

Example: This example will return you the count of employees with the last anme Coleridge.

`SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Employee WHERE LastName='Coleridge'");
int result = Convert.ToInt32(Cmd.ExecuteSaclar());`

Comment: I ended up correcting it to that, thanks for the input.